# Autocomplete behavior in vim

Tags: vimrc, autocompletion, gvim

I have autocomplpop plugin installed in my .vim directory. If I use gvim then autocompleting simply works automatically in insert mode without the need to press any CTRL-N to get the drop down list.

Is there a way I can emulate that in vim? Where in insert mode I have to press CTRL-N each time to get the drop down menu.

I recollect there was a way of doing that by adding something in .vimrc to emulate that but can't recollect those settings.

Thanks,
-ND

Comment: Doesn't that plugin support non-GUI vim? I don't see any mention of gvim being required here https://vim.sourceforge.io/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879

Answer (score 2):

As said by [B Layer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13449/autocomplete-behavior-in-vim#comment23062_13449), this kind of feature should not vary between terminal and GUI versions.

Make sure the plugin is enabled from your `vimrc` file, and **not** from `gvimrc`. If still not working, check the output of `:scriptnames` from both instances to see which files are loaded.

Comment: I have the following in my .vimrc                                                            `  **filetype plugin on
runtime! plugin/*.vim ** ` pressing ctrl-n does activate the drop down menu however I want that to happen by default without having the need to press ctrl-n in the insert mode.